# Connecting to Cassandra in Lagom Deveoper Box

Tags: cassandra, persistence, lagom

I am working with Lagom Framework with Chirper application. The application is up and runnin. I understand that In dev mode, by default, Cassandra is run on port 4000. 
I am unable to connect to the local Cassandra to browse the data and events.Any pointers on how to connect to the embedded cassandra that comes with lagom  so that I can view the events that are  getting stored.
The services running locally are as follows

```
http://localhost:8000/services

[{"name":"/loadtestservice","url":"http://0.0.0.0:51796"},{"name":"kafka_native","url":"tcp://localhost:9092/kafka_native"},{"name":"friendservice","url":"http://0.0.0.0:60399"},{"name":"chirper-front-end","url":"http://0.0.0.0:57143"},{"name":"chirpservice","url":"http://0.0.0.0:54485"},{"name":"activityservice","url":"http://0.0.0.0:51855"},{"name":"cas_native","url":"tcp://127.0.0.1:4000/cas_native"}]
```

Comment: Could you please add specific details about exactly what you tried? What commands you ran, and what errors you saw.

Comment: Are you sure that the application was running? because if it was, one would be able to connect to the port